# Cascading of persist, does not create identifiaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

Having this entities:

*User.java*:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name = "friend_id")
    private Map<User, Friendship> friends = new HashMap<>();
}
```

*Friendship.java*:

```
@Entity
@Data
@IdClass(Friendship.class)
public class Friendship implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long owner_id;
    @Id
    private Long friend_id;
    private String level;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("owner_id")
    private User owner;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("friend_id")
    private User friend;
}
```

and *DemoApplication.java*:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner loadData(UserRepository userRepo){
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                User owner = new User();
                owner.setUsername("owner");
                User f1 = new User();
                f1.setUsername("f1");
                User f2 = new User();
                f2.setUsername("f2");
                Friendship fs1 = new Friendship();
                fs1.setOwner(owner);
                fs1.setFriend(f1);
                Friendship fs2 = new Friendship();
                fs2.setOwner(owner);
                fs2.setFriend(f2);
                owner.getFriends().put(f1, fs1);
                owner.getFriends().put(f2, fs2);
                userRepo.saveAndFlush(owner);
            }
        };
    }
```

I get error:

```
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.demo.model.Friendship#Friendship(owner_id=null, friend_id=null, level=null, owner=com.example.demo.model.User@2b036135, friend=com.example.demo.model.User@a9e28af9)]
```

Which means both `User`s `f1` and `f2`, are having null in `Long id`. The indeed have, when the object is created, but I thought the mapping had specified `CascadeType.ALL` and `@GeneratedValue` so the if should be created.

But I had try to set the ids myself:

```
            ...
            f1.setUsername("f1");
            f1.setId(1L);
            User f2 = new User();
            f2.setUsername("f2");
            f2.setId(2L);
            ...
```

But now I got

```
detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User
```

So I guess I should let the creation of primary keys on JPA. But as you saw from above, it does not that even with Cascading. So what now?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this under your @Id annotation

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO` does not create column with auto increment try it...

Comment: It is used for generating id value, i never stated it CREATES a column.

Comment: So, why you remove `strategy=GenerationType.AUTO` from your answer

Comment: still the same error `A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`